# Альтернатива echo (PHP), но на Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Нужно вывести информацию из переменной. Как это сделать с помощью javascript?

**UPD**. Поставим вопрос чуть-чуть по-другому:  Как отобразить на странице адрес страницы, на которой сейчас находится посетитель, посредством **только** Javascript.

Решил проблему с помощью location.href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот функция, не проверял, но должна работать.

```
function echo () {
        // !No description available for echo. @php.js developers: Please update the function summary text file.
        // 
        // version: 1109.2015
        // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/echo    // +   original by: Philip Peterson
        // +   improved by: echo is bad
        // +   improved by: Nate
        // +    revised by: Der Simon (http://innerdom.sourceforge.net/)
        // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)    // +   bugfixed by: Eugene Bulkin (http://doubleaw.com/)
        // +   input by: JB
        // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
        // +   bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
        // +   bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)    // +   bugfixed by: EdorFaus
        // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
        // %        note 1: If browsers start to support DOM Level 3 Load and Save (parsing/serializing),
        // %        note 1: we wouldn't need any such long code (even most of the code below). See
        // %        note 1: link below for a cross-browser implementation in JavaScript. HTML5 might    // %        note 1: possibly support DOMParser, but that is not presently a standard.
        // %        note 2: Although innerHTML is widely used and may become standard as of HTML5, it is also not ideal for
        // %        note 2: use with a temporary holder before appending to the DOM (as is our last resort below),
        // %        note 2: since it may not work in an XML context
        // %        note 3: Using innerHTML to directly add to the BODY is very dangerous because it will    // %        note 3: break all pre-existing references to HTMLElements.
        // *     example 1: echo('<div><p>abc</p><p>abc</p></div>');
        // *     returns 1: undefined
        // Fix: This function really needs to allow non-XHTML input (unless in true XHTML mode) as in jQuery
        var arg = '',        argc = arguments.length,
            argv = arguments,
            i = 0,
            holder, win = this.window,
            d = win.document,        ns_xhtml = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
            ns_xul = 'http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul'; // If we're in a XUL context
        var stringToDOM = function (str, parent, ns, container) {
            var extraNSs = '';
            if (ns === ns_xul) {            extraNSs = ' xmlns:html="' + ns_xhtml + '"';
            }
            var stringContainer = '<' + container + ' xmlns="' + ns + '"' + extraNSs + '>' + str + '</' + container + '>';
            var dils = win.DOMImplementationLS,
                dp = win.DOMParser,            ax = win.ActiveXObject;
            if (dils && dils.createLSInput && dils.createLSParser) {
                // Follows the DOM 3 Load and Save standard, but not
                // implemented in browsers at present; HTML5 is to standardize on innerHTML, but not for XML (though
                // possibly will also standardize with DOMParser); in the meantime, to ensure fullest browser support, could            // attach http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/brettz9/DOMToString/DOM3.js (see http://svn2.assembla.com/svn/brettz9/DOMToString/DOM3.xhtml for a simple test file)
                var lsInput = dils.createLSInput();
                // If we're in XHTML, we'll try to allow the XHTML namespace to be available by default
                lsInput.stringData = stringContainer;
                var lsParser = dils.createLSParser(1, null); // synchronous, no schema type            return lsParser.parse(lsInput).firstChild;
            } else if (dp) {
                // If we're in XHTML, we'll try to allow the XHTML namespace to be available by default
                try {
                    var fc = new dp().parseFromString(stringContainer, 'text/xml');                if (fc && fc.documentElement && fc.documentElement.localName !== 'parsererror' && fc.documentElement.namespaceURI !== 'http://www.mozilla.org/newlayout/xml/parsererror.xml') {
                        return fc.documentElement.firstChild;
                    }
                    // If there's a parsing error, we just continue on
                } catch (e) {                // If there's a parsing error, we just continue on
                }
            } else if (ax) { // We don't bother with a holder in Explorer as it doesn't support namespaces
                var axo = new ax('MSXML2.DOMDocument');
                axo.loadXML(str);            return axo.documentElement;
            }
    /*else if (win.XMLHttpRequest) { // Supposed to work in older Safari
                var req = new win.XMLHttpRequest;
                req.open('GET', 'data:application/xml;charset=utf-8,'+encodeURIComponent(str), false);            if (req.overrideMimeType) {
                    req.overrideMimeType('application/xml');
                }
                req.send(null);
                return req.responseXML;        }*/
            // Document fragment did not work with innerHTML, so we create a temporary element holder
            // If we're in XHTML, we'll try to allow the XHTML namespace to be available by default
            //if (d.createElementNS && (d.contentType && d.contentType !== 'text/html')) { // Don't create namespaced elements if we're being served as HTML (currently only Mozilla supports this detection in true XHTML-supporting browsers, but Safari and Opera should work with the above DOMParser anyways, and IE doesn't support createElementNS anyways)
            if (d.createElementNS && // Browser supports the method        (d.documentElement.namespaceURI || // We can use if the document is using a namespace
            d.documentElement.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'html' || // We know it's not HTML4 or less, if the tag is not HTML (even if the root namespace is null)
            (d.contentType && d.contentType !== 'text/html') // We know it's not regular HTML4 or less if this is Mozilla (only browser supporting the attribute) and the content type is something other than text/html; other HTML5 roots (like svg) still have a namespace
            )) { // Don't create namespaced elements if we're being served as HTML (currently only Mozilla supports this detection in true XHTML-supporting browsers, but Safari and Opera should work with the above DOMParser anyways, and IE doesn't support createElementNS anyways); last test is for the sake of being in a pure XML document
                holder = d.createElementNS(ns, container);        } else {
                holder = d.createElement(container); // Document fragment did not work with innerHTML
            }
            holder.innerHTML = str;
            while (holder.firstChild) {            parent.appendChild(holder.firstChild);
            }
            return false;
            // throw 'Your browser does not support DOM parsing as required by echo()';
        };

        var ieFix = function (node) {
            if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                var newNode = d.createElement(node.nodeName);            var i, len;
                if (node.attributes && node.attributes.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0, len = node.attributes.length; i < len; i++) {
                        newNode.setAttribute(node.attributes[i].nodeName, node.getAttribute(node.attributes[i].nodeName));
                    }            }
                if (node.childNodes && node.childNodes.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0, len = node.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
                        newNode.appendChild(ieFix(node.childNodes[i]));
                    }            }
                return newNode;
            } else {
                return d.createTextNode(node.nodeValue);
            }    };

        var replacer = function (s, m1, m2) {
            // We assume for now that embedded variables do not have dollar sign; to add a dollar sign, you currently must use {$$var} (We might change this, however.)
            // Doesn't cover all cases yet: see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double        if (m1 !== '\\') {
                return m1 + eval(m2);
            } else {
                return s;
            }    };

        this.php_js = this.php_js || {};
        var phpjs = this.php_js,
            ini = phpjs.ini,        obs = phpjs.obs;
        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            arg = argv[i];
            if (ini && ini['phpjs.echo_embedded_vars']) {
                arg = arg.replace(/(.?)\{?\$(\w*?\}|\w*)/g, replacer);        }

            if (!phpjs.flushing && obs && obs.length) { // If flushing we output, but otherwise presence of a buffer means caching output
                obs[obs.length - 1].buffer += arg;
                continue;        }

            if (d.appendChild) {
                if (d.body) {
                    if (win.navigator.appName === 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') { // We unfortunately cannot use feature detection, since this is an IE bug with cloneNode nodes being appended                    d.body.appendChild(stringToDOM(ieFix(arg)));
                    } else {
                        var unappendedLeft = stringToDOM(arg, d.body, ns_xhtml, 'div').cloneNode(true); // We will not actually append the div tag (just using for providing XHTML namespace by default)
                        if (unappendedLeft) {
                            d.body.appendChild(unappendedLeft);                    }
                    }
                } else {
                    d.documentElement.appendChild(stringToDOM(arg, d.documentElement, ns_xul, 'description')); // We will not actually append the description tag (just using for providing XUL namespace by default)
                }        } else if (d.write) {
                d.write(arg);
            }
    /* else { // This could recurse if we ever add print!
                print(arg);        }*/
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не работает, изменил вопрос. Теперь, думаю, более понятно, что мне нужно. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: В таком случае вот:
<pre><div id=resultdiv></div>
<script>
var hrf = document.location.href;
document.getElementById('resultdiv').innerHTML = hrf;
// Либо alert(hrf)
// Либо document.write(hrf);
</script></pre>

Answer (score 2):

```
document.write("Текущий URL " + document.URL)
```

Попробуйте так.

Comment: Решил проблему с помощью location.href.